# How do I limit the current drawn by a DC fan to increase battery life?

Tags: current, battery-operated

I have a simple 5 volt DC circuit powered by a LiON battery.  Running a fan that is rated at 5 volts 100mA-300mA.  The battery has a 1000mA output max so the fan draws its full 300mA.  I am looking for a way to lower the current available to the fan to 100mA so I can, in theory, triple my battery life.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: PWM.. .. .. .. .

Comment: But for you, the simplest way to do it might be to connect the fan to the battery, assuming your battery is around 3.6V, and that should drop the power consumption of the fan by quite a bit.

Comment: If you want to reduce the current to 100 mA, all you have to do is probably to let it spin up.

Comment: @user3528438 this is very very bad for lithium ion cells. You should always use active protection circuitry; overdischarging permanently reduces battery capacity.

Comment: Put one or more diodes in series. If it is still capable of running (it works on 9V and 12V fans, not sure about 5V ones) it will run slower and will use less power.

Comment: One diode will likely be enough. Roughly a 1/4 of the power used after the reduction will be dissipated as heat in the diode, but the total power used will be reduced enough to make it worthwhile to waste that much.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered... ok, one diode...can you give me a spec on the diode?  What about a current limiting diode like they use for LEDs?  (You would never believe I have an EE, but in my defense, have not used my education in over 30 years)

Comment: 1n4001 to 1n4008, but practically any common silicon diode would do. Avoid Germanium and Schottky diodes since its the voltage drop you're after.

Answer (score 3):

The fan will draw less current when it is given less volts. The current draw is roughly proportional to applied volts as is the speed. Consult the fan manufacturers specs and/or check on a variable lab supply to obtain a minimum voltage for reliable operation.

Lower fan voltages will mean that less air is shifted. Now make some PWM to control the fan and you will save battery power. If you run the fan at say 70% speed meaning about 70% voltage and about 70% current then power is halved if your proposed PWM system is perfect.

What you can do is connect your PWM control to a temp sensor so the fan speeds up when hot shifting its full specified amount of air and slows down when cold saving the battery and making less noise and increasing bearing life. Sure this is more complicated than a resistor but these days it is worth it when SMD is used.

Comment: Yes, you can make simple PWM circuit using a 556 and a MOSFET, @David. Run it at 2 kHz and put an adjustable resistor preset in to twiddle the PWM mark:space ratio 'til you're happy.

Comment: GreatScott has a good video where he uses PWM with a 12V fan, but the concept should be almost the same.  [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-swETkSPyYM)

Answer (score -1):

A 50 ohm resistor would limit the max current to 100 mA. But that might be too much.  How about a 50 ohm pot and adjust it till you get the current you want.

Comment: This burns up the excess current as heat in the potentiometer.

Comment: While a resistor will reduce current, it's hardly the best way to increase battery life.

Comment: yeah, thats 5 watts down the drain

Comment: @Makoto - Would you care to try again? Modelling the fan as a 16.7 ohm resistor, putting a 33 ohm limiting resistor in series drops the current to 100 mA, and wasted power is 0.33 watts.